# Time looping an average

Tags: sql, ms-access, time

I have a table with 17,000 records that is ordered by time spaced in 15 minute intervals. The time values loop back onto themselves every 24 hours, so for example, I could have 100 records that are all at 1 AM, just on different days. I want to create a 'average day' by taking those 100 records at 1 am and finding the average of them for the averaged 1 am.

I don't know how to format the table to make it show up nicely here.

Comment: Simply run an aggregate on the time column but please show data so we can advise further.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to calculate the average value per time interval regardless of the day in a query. You could use this SQL to group your table by Time interval only (assuming that it's separate from the date field), and average whichever fields you want to average. Do not select or group by the date field, just select and group by the time field.

```
SELECT TimeField
  , AVG([Field1ToAverage])
  , AVG([Field2ToAverage]) 
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY TimeField;
```

If the date and time fields are stored together in the same column, you will have to extract the time only:

```
SELECT TimeValue([DateTimeField])
  , AVG([Field1ToAverage])
  , AVG([Field2ToAverage]) 
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY TimeValue([DateTimeField]);
```